# Removing .html# from URL (Stripe:Flask:NGINX setup):

Tags: python, nginx, flask, directory, stripe-payments

**Background**:

I've been following this [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) and this [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04) guide.

Currently, I'm up to step 6 on the digital ocean guide, in regards to setting up the stripe server, hence, I
have the NGINX proxying to a Gunicorn sock for stripe.

**Problem**:

But, before step 7 (HTTPS), I want to tell flask to remove the .html# from my URLs, for example:

This:

Example.com/checkout/x

Instead of this:

Example.com/checkout/x.html#

**Current Setup**:

For further clarity:

My current code looks similar to this:

```
import os

from flask import Flask... blah

import stripe

super secret stripe.api_key = 123abc

app = Flask(_ _name_ _,
        static_url_path='',
        static_folder='public'
)

your domain ='http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4242'

@app.route('/create-checkout-session', methods = ['get', 'post'])

def create_checkout_session():
Rest of code.
```

My directory is structured like this:

- My Project

  - myproject.py
  - public

    - Checkout

      - prodA.html
      - prodB.html
      - prodA.css

**Solutions Tried:**

Further, I've tried many solutions, but the two most important are:

Using flask to render a template:

```
@app.route(/) 
    def showtemp()
     Return render_template('index.html')
```

Which has been tried Two times; with the index file in an user created public folder and template folder, both failing to render as the file can't be found.

I've also tried this in NGINX:

```
.*$ $1.html last;
```

Which works for removing the html, but it does not render the css.

**Therefore**:

I'll appreciate any and all suggestions on how to get this to work, or even just being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: To skip every URI with the filename extension (e.g. `.css`, `.js`, etc.) you can try `if ($uri !~ \.\w+$) rewrite ^ $uri.html last; }` or `rewrite ^(?!.*\.\w+$) $uri.html last;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky I appreciate the reply, the code works for the checkout pages, but it conflicts with the /checkout-session-page giving an error of: "this method is not allowed".

Comment: Got it to work by just passing the original code no regex to the checkout-session-page and using your improved regex, thanks.